# When this javascript function get called?

Tags: asp.net

I have created one page.In that page,I wrote one javascript function for displaying character count,when user enter something in textbox.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "DisplayCharCount()");
}
```

First time pageload,textbox is blank. Textbox does not have autopostback== true.After
pageload,user enter text into textbox.This time page is not loaded again.So when this function get called?

Comment: why cant you call this script in markup?

Answer (score 1):

`Page_Load` will call everytime a page reloaded. so `onkeyup` will bind to the textbox everytime a page reloaded.

> When this function get called?

This event is triggered when the user releases a Key while typing on TextBox1.

You can also bind it for the first time only:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "DisplayCharCount()");
    }
}
```

Or you can also bind it directly as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" onkeyup="DisplayCharCount()">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Page_Load` method is called every time a user requests the page. The `DisplayCharCount` method is called whenever a user pressed a key (that is, release the key) in the `TextBox1` element.